# How to get item in RecyclerView when select this item in Spinner in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, spinner

How to link Spinner items with RecyclerView items? I have added Spinner in actionBar and fill it with some items like (first, third...) and when choose item like (third) how to get third item in RecyclerView to come to top screen. And when scroll in RecyclerView the items change in Spinner depend on RecyclerView items.